# Volume of pyramid with 2 toppoints

Tags: 3d, volume, solid-geometry

I know how to calculate a pyramid's volume when I have the base and perpendicular height to the 1 toppoint. It's by

$$\frac13 \cdot \mbox{base} \cdot \mbox{height}$$

However, what if the top is not a point, but a line? Is this easy to calculate?

Also, is there a difference between an pyramid with a regular rectangle as base, and a pyramid with some other shaped base (for example a irregular plane with 6 points.). Cause at the end I need to calculate it for a pyramid with an irregular base. But, at first, an rectangle as base would be a good start.

edit:
for clearification: line E-F is parallel to plan ABCD:

[image]

for clearification: line E-F is parallel to plane ABCD and line CD:

[image]

the second one can be splitted in a prisma and a piramid, but how about the first one?

Comment: @Goodqustion. Your question is not clear and it will also be closed in here. You have to ask first for  a pyramid with a rectangle base and a line on the top. You may get an answer.

Comment: why? The formula 1/3*base*height does also count for ALL base shapes right? not just a rectangle... but ok... i will change it if you like.

Comment: You mean a roof shape with 2 identical trapezoids and two identical isosceles triangles ?

Comment: yeah when talking about a regular rectangle as base you might say that. However, I didn't say the topline is parallel to a baseline. but would that matter? guess not?

Comment: There are two immediate ways forward: $(1)$ break up your figure into a variety of easily calculable areas, and add them up, or $(2)$ find a way to parameterize the figure in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and integrate the volume.

Comment: yeah i was afraid for that. Only thing that bothers me... if for a pyramid with a toppoint it is so freaking easy with the called formula, how can it suddenly be so freaking hard when its a line. My intuition says there must be a very easy formula for it to. but okay. maybe i have to wait 200 years for that :-). Guess my client ain't gonna accept that answer.. :-) i'm drawing it in autocad civil 3d now and calculate it that way. thanks anyhow.

Comment: One way would be to derive a formula such as the pyramid example here:[Volume Problem](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/MoreVolume.aspx). Find the cross sectional area which may be the triangle. So the “base” and “height” formulas may be needed.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

A simple form

In figure top of the pyramid is a line , lower height is h and higher height is k. Base is rectangle , sides a and b.Suppose the coordinates of lower top is $(0, \frac b2, h$ and that of higher top is $(a, \frac b2, k)$; The slope of the line on the top is:

$m=\frac{k-h}a$

So the equation of the line on the top is:

Or: $z=\frac{k-h}a x+h$

The volume of pyramid is:

$$V=\int^b_0dy\int^a_0 dx\int^{z=\frac{k-h}x x+h}_0 dz=\frac {k-h}a a^2b+abh$$

Example: a=4, b=2, k=3, h=2:

$V=\frac{3-2}4\times  4^2\times 2+4\times 2\times 2= 24$

If you put $h=0$ the figure becomes a pyramid and it's volume is:

$V=\frac14\times 4^2\times 2=8 $

We compare his with when top is a point:

$v=\frac 13 \times 4\times 2=\frac 83$

If the line on top is parallel with zy plane at hight h, then there will be a triangle on side(on ZY plane) it;s area is $A=\frac 12 bh$ and the volume of pyramid is $V= A.b=\frac12 abh$. For example a=4, b=2 and h=3 $\rightarrow V=\frac12 \cdot 4\cdot 2\cdot3=12$. If base is irregular but we know its area and also the legth of the line on the top, then we can find volume as:

$b=\frac Aa$

where  A is area of base, a legth of the line on the top and b is equivalent width of the base if rectangular . So volume is:

$V=\frac12 ab h =\frac 12 Ah$

The volume of figure in your question is:

$V= A_{ABCD}\times\frac{h_{AED}+h_{BFC}}2$

where $A_{ABCD}$ is the area of base ABCD and $h_{AED}$ and $h_{BFC}$ are the heights of walls AED and BFC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't fully follow it. Next to that I don't know if the image is wrong or if i'm interpreting it wrong, so added a picture to my first post. However. Your first step: what is z-0? and x-0? I don't understand this. Are you calculation the length of the topline by the ratio???

Comment: I edited my answer and changed the form of presentation. Hope it helps.

Comment: Don't know what you see as height, the height of the top (point E or F) perpendicular to the surface ABCD? Or the height of the top (point E or F) to the baseline of the triangle (line AB or line BC). However, I drawn the figure in Civil, with base 2 x 2, and height of line EF perp to base ABCD 2, and get an result different from your fomula. When doing Aabcd = 2x2 = 4, and h is smallest = (2+2)/2, this gives 4 x 2 = 8 which would be volume of the cube, it's easy to see the volume should be less then that.

Comment: Yes the walls are supposed to be perpendicular on surface. If they are not then you have 3 pyramids joined; one in the middle with  vertical walls and two other with wall having slope with surface.In this case you must have the slopes.